# When to use const references over const value in function?

Tags: c++, performance, reference, constants

On a 64-bit system, `const&` is 8 bytes. For values and objects smaller than 8 bytes, it makes sense to pass by value rather than reference. Even an 8 byte object is cheaper to copy than to pass the reference, then access the object.

At what threshold should you prefer a const reference over a const value?

Comment: If it's important, I measure it. Otherwise, I don't worry about it.

Comment: It seriously depends on the object and copy constructor. Your object can be holding just an 8-byte pointer pointing to a 10Mb memory block. And by passing by value you might be invoking copy-constructor that will be making a copy of these 10Mb of data...

Comment: you does not win anything if you pass it by value since the wordlength is still 8 bytes and also the registers that are used for the arguments (that may depends from the calling convention)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> For values and objects smaller than 8 bytes, it makes sense to pass by value rather than reference. Even an 8 byte object is cheaper to copy than to pass the reference, then access the object.

References are not guaranteed to be implemented as pointers. In fact as per §8.3.2/4:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage

---

> At what threshold should you prefer a const reference over a const value?

The situation is pretty simple:

- use *const references* when you just want to read the value
- use *value* when you will always end up making a copy of the object inside the function
- use *reference* when you want to modify the object inside the function